# Some digital watches display digits in black on a white background and in the dark the backlight is reversed. How is this possible?

Tags: optics, polarization

Some digital watches display digits in black on a white background and in the dark the backlight is reversed, blue on a black background. How is this possible?

Here is an example:
[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/7196xuw29OL.*UL1500*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/7196xuw29OL._UL1500_.jpg)

Usually the backlight is black on a blue background and it's very easy to explain:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzRCDLre1b4

But even after searching everywhere I did not find an explanation to the case mentioned

The only hypothesis I have (and which I do not really believe)
is that the electroluminescent backlight is located between the LCD and the second polarizer
and that the light it emits is polarized perpendicularly to the second polarizer
and that it is transparent when it is off

Edit:

I may have mistaken the title

In reality the background does not really change, it is the digits that go from black to light (light blue)

Besides, under an external light the effect is clearly visible

Here's a video that shows the effect I'm talking about: 
around 2:36
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEpXyujMHaM

By analyzing frame by frame when the backlight switch
we see that the digits change without the background is really changed

It does not seem to be a reversal of the screen when the backlight is switched on
since the bottom does not change

Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

The other way to invert an LCD so the digit segments and the background are "flipped" is to have extra LCD elements built into the background which can be switched on and off independently of the digit segments. When you want backlit segments against a black background, you de-energize the segments and energize the background. When you want backlit background and dark digit segments, you do the opposite.

Comment: Clever idea though I think that is not the case i'm referring to.
I did kind of mistaken the title, so I did add a link showing what I meant

Answer (score 0):

In a typical LCD panel with two linear polarizers, rotating either linear polarizer by 90 degrees will invert the colors. For instance, if the linear polarizers are originally cross-oriented (as in the Wikipedia article) so that applying a bias across the liquid crystal prevents the system from transmitting light, rotating one of the polarizers so that the polarization axes are parallel will cause the light to be transmitted almost entirely. The situation without bias is also similarly flipped. [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g71MwIvl00s) demonstrating this.